# Understanding NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

I'm trying to get the hang of `NOT EXISTS` and am having some trouble.
Say I have a 2 tables.

```
Employees:
+------+------+
| eid  | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | Bob  |
| 2    | Alice|
| 3    | Jill |
+------+------+

Transactions:
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| tid      | eid      | type     | amount    |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 1        | Deposit  | 50        |
| 2        | 1        | Open     | 500       |
| 3        | 3        | Open     | 200       |
| 4        | 2        | Withdraw | 25        |
| 5        | 2        | Open     | 100       |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Let's say I want to find the names of all the employees that have not opened any account with the amount of $250 or higher. This means that I only want the rows where an employee has opened an account of amount < $250.
Right now I have something like this...

```
SELECT name FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.type <> 'Open' AND t.amount >= 250 AND t.eid = e.eid);
```

This is obviously wrong and I don't really understand why.

Comment: " This means that I only want the rows where an employee has opened an account of amount < $250. " --- so you want users with transactions with `OPEN` and `< 250`?

Comment: I think your question is a little vague:  "Employees that have not opened any account with the amount of $250 or higher" is different from "Employees that have opened an account with the amount of less than $250".  The first case would include employees who have never opened an account.  Which are you after?

Comment: Sorry about that. Only the employees that have opened an account with the amount less than $250.

Comment: SQLPlus is the commandline of **Oracle**, which is something completely different than MySQL. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine an `EXISTS` with a `NOT EXISTS` since you "only want the rows where an employee has opened an account of amount < $250.":

```
SELECT name FROM Employees e
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Transactions t
   WHERE t.amount < 250 AND t.type='Open' AND t.eid = e.eid)
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Transactions t
   WHERE t.amount >= 250 AND t.eid = e.eid);
```

You need the `EXISTS` to ensure that only employee are returned which have an open account with amount < 250 at all. The `NOT EXISTS` is required to ensure that not employee are included which have additional accounts with amount >= 250.

[**Here's a sql-fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1faa3/1/0)

Comment: Type is to make sure that we are only selecting a row that is opening a new account.

Comment: @user1378863: i've edited the answer to take that into account. Note that you must use both `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` here to ensure that only employee are returned with an 'open' account <250 and not those which also have  additional tranactions with amount greater than 250.

Comment: Only the account opening figure was mentioned. Do you need `AND t.type='Open'` in the `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: This query does not give me the expected answer for some reason. I do understand the logic though.

Comment: @user1378863: That's the result if i use your sample data above. I've added another transaction(the last row) to demonstrate the `NOT EXISTS` because then "Jill" has one account more with amount >250. Therefor she will not be selected anymore. Is that not desired?

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that. I seemed to have confused myself some more somewhere along the way and also did not realize you added another entry into the table. You have it correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see - is that you've used `<>` for transaction type, not `=`

```
SELECT name FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT null FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.transaction_type = 'Open' AND t.amount >= 250 AND t.eid = e.eid);
```

After you edited your question the answer would be:

```
SELECT name FROM Employees e
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT null FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.transaction_type = 'Open' AND t.amount < 250 AND t.eid = e.eid);
```

Comment: That is because I am trying to select rows that have the type as 'Open'. Maybe I am understanding NOT EXISTS incorrectly, but if I use <>, then wouldn't NOT EXISTS return the rows with only 'Open'?

Comment: @user1378863: "Let's say I want to find the names of all the employees that have not opened any account with the amount of $250 or higher" --- this means you want `= OPEN` transactions for amount `>= 250`

Comment: Your answer does give me the right result, but I want to know how it can be done with `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @user1378863: "but I want to know how it can be done with NOT EXISTS" --- programmers solve **real** issues. Your issue isn't good to do with `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I understand that. I'm just trying to challenge myself so I can understand `NOT EXISTS` better.

Comment: @user1378863: it is the same as `EXISTS` but the opposite

Comment: @zerkms: Speak for yourself. I'm obsessive so if a specific piece of syntax has flummoxed me I will beat it into submission by way of taking a break for some fun and personal improvement, before moving on to what I have discovered is the better approach. Though yes in some cases that's so completely pointless as to not even bother with that in my spare time...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an LEFT JOIN instead of a sub select.

```
SELECT name FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN Transactions t
ON e.eid = t.eid
WHERE t.tid IS NULL
OR t.type <> 'Open'
OR t.amount <= 250;
```

This will join all transaction records, and then only include records where a transaction does not exist, the user has a non-open transaction, or the amount doesn't meet the reuiqred $250

Comment: But it's not what OP wants. He wants to know the employee with an account(type='Open', amount <250) which **don't have** an additional acount(anount>=250). You would also repeat the names.

Comment: A join is not a replacement for a sub-select.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: There's no indication that additional accounts are possible. Seems to me `eid` represents a single employee's single account, mainly because otherwise the transactions for a single employee's multiple accounts would all be mixed together.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Even in OP's limited sample data there are multiple transactions(=accounts) with the same `eid`(employee).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I overlooked that. In that case, my answer won't suffice.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In what universe are transactions == accounts? You perform multiple transactions on an account (_one_ such transaction is the "Open" transaction for that account, which is what the OP is talking about), and there is no indication here that we must support multiple accounts per employee (quite the contrary in fact).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right, i've misunderstood the terms(actually i have no idea of this subject). However, what matters is that there are multiple transactions for one employee and maybe also employee without a transaction.